# how to copy all tables from one database to another

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 databases, one called ACCNT and one called DUMMY which im going to use as a temp database when restoring the accnt database. ACCNT has about 50 tables in it that all need to be copied to dummy with out the data, just the empty tables. How can I do this with out manually copying all the create table codes from each of the tables. Ive tried that and it works, its just way too time consuming to do for all 50 tables. Any help is appreciated

Comment: if your db is SQL SERVER, just take a backup of your database and restore it on the temp database.

Comment: you dont have to make the tables to restore to beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [generate scripts for these 50 tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245282.aspx) (optionally *without* the data, as you need).

Another thing you could do (if you don't care about copying over things like indexes and constraints) is script this out for all 50 tables:

```
select *
into YourDestinationDatabase.dbo.Table1
from YourSourceDatabase.dbo.Table1;

select *
into YourDestinationDatabase.dbo.Table2
from YourSourceDatabase.dbo.Table2;

select *
into YourDestinationDatabase.dbo.Table3
from YourSourceDatabase.dbo.Table3;

-- ... so on and so forth
```